# Drawing horizontal bar chart with `MPAndroidChart`

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Does anybody have an idea on how to make this: [my app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JfXL.png) look like this: [how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSh5r.png)?

My question is: how to make each line of the Horizontal Bar Chart fill between the two lines?

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Float>> iterator = structuredData.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Map.Entry<String, Float> entry = iterator.next();
                //i*10 => starting position of the bar
                horizontalBarChartArr.add(new BarEntry((i*10), entry.getValue()));
                names.add(entry.getKey());
                i++;
            }

            XAxis xAxis = horizontalBarChart.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
                @Override
                public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                    return names.get((int)value % names.size());
                }
            });

            xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
            xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
            BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(horizontalBarChartArr, "Day Expenses");
            barDataSet.setColors(Color.RED);
            BarData data = new BarData(barDataSet);
            data.setBarWidth(9f);
            horizontalBarChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
            Description a = new Description();
            a.setText("");
            horizontalBarChart.setDescription(a);
            horizontalBarChart.invalidate();
            horizontalBarChart.animateY(1200);
            horizontalBarChart.setData(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example to your case:

https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine

It´s Automatically exported from code.google.com/p/achartengine

[image]

Comment: When it comes to add more lines this one does not work good for me. This is an option(if I have less data), but honestlly I prefer to use MPAndroidChart Library.